# Passing functions in parameter, to be run on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the global function that runs on load:

```
$.fn.loadfns = function(specificfns) {
    $('#wrapper').hide();
    $('#load').fadeIn(400);
    $(window).load( function() {
        $('#load').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('#wrapper').fadeIn(600, function() {
                specificfns;
            })
        })
    });
};
```

Problem is, some pages require additional functions to be run after load (like inserting events into glDatePicker), so I'm trying to pass them as parameters for loadfns, like

```
$.fn.loadfns("alert('I won't be run');");
```

But nothing happens, it's not executed. If I do

```
... rest of function ...
$('#wrapper').fadeIn(600, function() {
    alert(specificfns);
})
```

It alerts "alert('I won't be run');" (without brackets) which should work as a function.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I read that one too, it didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a function around, you pass a *function* around, not a string.

If you want to allow just one extra function (which can, of course, call others):

```
$.fn.loadfns = function(extraFunction) {
$('#wrapper').hide();
$('#load').fadeIn(400);
$(window).load( function() {
  $('#load').fadeOut(400, function() {
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn(600, function() {
        if (extraFunction) {
            extraFunction();
        }
    })
  })
});
};
```

Used like this:

```
$("....").loadfns(function() {
     alert("Do something");
});
```

If you want to allow multiple extra functions, pass in an array:

```
$.fn.loadfns = function(extraFunctions) {
$('#wrapper').hide();
$('#load').fadeIn(400);
$(window).load( function() {
  $('#load').fadeOut(400, function() {
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn(600, function() {
        var index;

        if (extraFunctions) {
            for (index = 0; index < extraFunctions.length; ++index) {
                extraFunctions[index]();
            }
        }
    })
  })
});
};
```

(Of course, if you're in an ES5-enabled environment or using a shim, you might use `forEach` instead of the `for` loop.)

Used like this:

```
$("....").loadfns([doSomething, doSomethingElse]);

function doSomething() { /* ... */ }
function doSomethingElse() { /* ... */ }
// They don't have to be named, it's just clearer this way than with inline ones
```

You might consider putting `try/catch` blocks around the calls to the functions if you want to handle exceptions from them.

Comment: Thank you! It works, and it makes me feel stupid! I'll accept your answer as soon as the time limit's up.

Comment: @NovAlex: LOL Glad that helped, and sorry, wasn't meant to make you feel stupid. :-)